# PWA in angular configuration ngsw-manifest.json

Tags: angularjs, json, progressive-web-apps

Hello i want to configure my PWA app.
My app works fine except dynamic content api. When online it working fine but when i go offline i get status 503 from serviceWorker. 
My config file:
ngsw-manifest.json

```
{
  "dynamic": {
    "group": [{
      "name": "api",
      "urls": {
        "https:url": {
          "match": "prefix"
        }
      },
      "cache": {
        "optimizeFor": "freshness",
        "maxAgeMs": 3600000,
        "maxEntries": 20,
        "strategy": "lru"
      }
    }]
  },
  "external": {
    "urls": [{
      "url": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/issues/168) which stated that by creating a dynamic cache group, matching files that are fetched by the Service Worker will also be cached. This was due to the fetch method making a request and resolving the promise with the actual response from the server which was 503. Because of this the fetchFromCache code block is never executed and you are left with 503s. See the explanation in this [link](https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/issues/179).

Comment: i found file freshness.ts and change line to: if (rse.response === null || !rse.response.ok) {.... 
after build again clear service worker still same error any other think i can do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your app on Firebase you might want to look into using the new Firestore database. It's is designed for offline data. Firebase had issues with PWAs in Offline Mode. Also, the core of PWAs (ServiceWorker) has been rewritten in Angular 5.

Comment: angular 5 ? i use api from other server.